# Few-shot Learning with Retrieval Augmented Language

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model

Is it possible to use Few Shot Learning in Retrieval Augmented Language ?

I can use the few shot separately
and create a rag with template
but I couldn't use the few shot template in Retrieval Augmented Language

```
#prompt few shot
prompt = FewShotPromptTemplate(
    examples=examples,
    example_prompt=example_prompt,
    suffix="Pergunta: {input}",
    input_variables=["input"]
                              )

#retrievalRAG
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm, 
                 chain_type= 'stuff', 
                 retriever=retriever,
                 verbose=True,
                 return_source_documents=True)
```

Comment: Facing the exact same issue, have you found a solution ?

Comment: I didn't find the solution